# Apps Script Regex - Case Insensitive

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, re2

I am writing an apps script for Google Docs. I am using findText() to locate an instance of a specified string of characters.

By default, it is case sensitive and I need to remove that, but I can't figure out how to add the /i to the re2 regex so that it works in apps script engine.

In my example, I am trying for find all instances of micssys (e.g. micssys, Micssys, MICSSYS, etc).

Right now I have:

```
var text = "micssys";
var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(text);
```

I have tried:

```
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText("/"+text+"/i");

var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(text+"/i");

var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(text+"(i)");
```

None of these work.  What am I missing

Comment: Try `(?i)`..don't have any experience with gApps RegEx, but that is the right syntax (instead of `(i)`).

Comment: `(?i)+text` works. @Sam was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall, I believe you can create a new regexp object and use `exec` here.

```
var re = new RegExp('\\bmicssys\\b','gi');

var match;
var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
while (match = re.exec(bodyElement)) {
   // match[0] will return the found results
}
```

**Note**: You may have to use `getText()` to retrieve the contents of the element as a text string and then match against.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot find function match in object DocumentBodySection.`

Comment: Glad I could help here.