# How to use findText case insensitive?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs, re2

I try to search for a string in Google Document. By default `findText` is case sensitive. How can I use it case insensitive.

The reference says "Searches the contents of the element for the specified text pattern using regular expressions."

That's what I tried:

```
function search(string) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(string, "gi");
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rangeElement = body.findText(pattern);
  while (rangeElement) {
    var offset =rangeElement.getStartOffset();
    var text = rangeElement.getElement().asText().getText();
    html += text;
  } 
}
```

But it doesn't find anything. I also tried:

`body.findText(pattern(string));` and `body.findText(/string/\i);`

Anything else I can try?

Comment: What's the "type" of the argument that `findText()`  accepts?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23901030/4629261) on an other question may help you.

Comment: @Vinz Yes, I saw that one. But I am not shure, if that is really the only option. So it is really not possible to use findText for case insensitive search? The advantage of findText is, that it does deliver an RangeElement directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Issues:

- Sending Regexp "object" instead of "string" type to `findText()`
- Incorrect syntax for case insensitivity.

#### Solution:

- Use proper re2 syntax
- Send regex as string. This means special characters`\s` are double escaped `\\s`

  ```
  findText('(?i)Apple') //matches APPLE or AppLe
  ```

#### To Read:

- [Body#findText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern)
- [re2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: Great! Thank seems to work! But I have some results, that I really do not understand! For example the results for "Radio" and "radio" are different. "Radio" shows more results - even though both do find uppercase and lowercase and words like "radioactiv". I can't see the reason for that. Does anyone know that issue?

Comment: @wep Ask a different question providing [mcve], i.e., clearly defined sample data, code and the outputs in each case.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will investigate a little more and do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As we can read in the official [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern),

> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully
>   supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

In addition, be attentive to use pattern argument of the findText(): it must be a **string**, not RegExp object.

Comment: Case-insensitive is however supported.

Comment: @TheMaster How do I use case insenstive search then?